# How to write Junit for method call inside another method?

Tags: java, junit, junit4

```java
public class Account{

    public String getAcctNo(int accno){
        String cardno = getcreditCard();
        return accno + ":" + cardno;
    }

    public String creditCard(){
        Random rand = new Random();

        int one = rand.nextInt(1000);
        int two = rand.nextInt(1000);
        int three = rand.nextInt(1000);
        int four = rand.nextInt(1000);

        return one + "-" + two + "-" + three + "-" + four;
    }
}
```

I am writing unit test like below, but I think we should write without mock for this case.

```java
public class AccountDetailsTestCase {

    @Test
    public void testAccountNo() {
        Account account = mock(Account.class);

        when(account.creditCard()).thenReturn("101-102-103-104");

        assertEquals(account.creditCard(), "101-102-103-104");

        when(account.getAcctNo(10110)).thenReturn("10110:101-102-103-104");

        String expected = "10110:101-102-103-104";
        String result = account.getAcctNo(10110);

        assertEquals(expected, result);
    }
}
```

Can you advice how we can write unit test for the above scenario. I need help to write JUnit for the method call creditCard which is inside getAcctNo method. Note: above code is just a scenario so please advise on how I can write JUnit for the method call inside a method.

Comment: What is the meaning of the `creditCard()` method? Every time you call this method you get a different credit card number. Is that what this method should do? Also what is the purpose of the `getAcctNo()` method and why does it require an integer argument? Shouldn't this method be without arguments? Please [edit] your question to include a description what these methods should do or what the plan is they should do.

Comment: creditcard number should be generated for all the transaction. so just to show the code in simple assume i have method getAcctNo() which will get the account number from db or other source and inside this method i am calling the creditcard number. Here credit is generated when a transaction(getAcctNo()) is made. please advice how i can write junit for the getAcctNo() in which it calls creditcard() inside it.

Answer (score 1):

Currently your test does not test a single line of your logic.

```
when(account.creditCard()).thenReturn("101-102-103-104");
assertEquals(account.creditCard(), "101-102-103-104");
```

Here you are basically just testing ff your mock works.
Same thing for this part of your test.

```
when(account.getAcctNo(10110)).thenReturn("10110:101-102-103-104");
String expected = "10110:101-102-103-104";
String result = account.getAcctNo(10110);
assertEquals(expected, result);
```

When testing you should ask yourself what is the **visible behaviour** of your code? That is the stuff you want to test. In your case I guess it would be the String concatenation here:

```
return accno + ":" + cardno;
```

This is the part that should not be mocked because it is the thing you want to test.

---

Another problem I see is in the class design itself.
The `accno` (accountNumber I guess?) and the `cardno` (cardNumber?) are properties of your `Account` and should be stored in member variables.
If you change your `Account` to this design testing your logic becomes fairly easy:

```
public class Account {

    private String accno;
    private String cardno;

    public Account(String accno, String cardno) {
        this.accno = accno;
        this.cardno = cardno;
    }

    public String getAcctNo() {
        return accno + ":" + cardno;
    }
    
    // getter and setter for accno and cardno
}
```

Now you can simply pass the information about the `Account` via the constructor and test the logic of `::getAcctNo()`

```
@Test
public void testAccountNo() {
    
    Account account = new Account("10110", "101-102-103-104");
    String acctNo = account.getAcctNo();
    
    assertEquals("10110:101-102-103-104", acctNo);
}
```

Comment: No i want to have credicard method separately and that need to be called from getAcctNo method. how can write the unit test case for getAcctNo with the call to creditcard method.